# Pixel is there but .getpixel isn't detecting it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, opencv

I'm currently having an issues with my program that im not too sure how to fix.

I am doing the following:

```py
x = 0
y = 0
im = ImageGrab.grab()
time.sleep(1)
while True:
    xy = (x, y)
    x = x + 1
    if im.getpixel(xy) == (0,158,187):
        time.sleep(0.3)
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        break
    if x >= 1200:
        x = 0
        y = y + 1
        print('cant find pixel')
    if y >= 950:
        y = 0
        x = 0
```

And it works about 90% of the time and then theres this random time it just says it can't detect the pixel despite the pixel being there 100%.

EDIT: Managed to catch the following error in the 10% it happens:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getpixel'`

Which makes no sense since I'm doing `im = ImageGrab.grab()` beforehand and it works 90% of the time

Comment: The problem is not that it can't detect the pixel.  The problem is that `ImageGrab.grab` has failed.  You probably need to check for that and retry later.  Why do you wait for a second after grabbing the screen before searching the bitmap?

Comment: @TimRoberts no specific reason, the thing is that this program is meant to run 8 hours non stop if needed, I can't have ImageGrab.grab randomly fail for no reason.

I found a semi fix by doing:
while True:
    if im is None:
     im = ImageGrab.grab()
    else:
     break

Issue is that it sometimes still happens somehow...

Answer (score 1):

You should check your `ImageGrab()` was successful before using the data, so something like:

```
im = ImageGrab.grab()
if im is not None:
   processImage
```

---

You'll be there all day if you run double `for` loops over an image and call a function for every one! Try to get in the habit of using Numpy vectorised code for images in Python.

Basically, you appear to be testing if any pixel in your 1200x950 image matches all three RGB components `(0,158,187)`.

You can do that with Numpy like this:

```
 np.any(np.all(na==(0,158,187), axis=-1))
```

In the demo below the double `for` loops take 800ms and the Numpy test takes 20ms, so 40x faster.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def loopy(im):
   for x in range(im.width):
      for y in range(im.height):
         if im.getpixel((x,y)) == crucialPixel:
            return True

   return False


def me(im):
    # Make image into Numpy array
    na = np.array(im)
    # Test if there is any pixel where all RGB components match crucialPixel
    return np.any(np.all(na==crucialPixel, axis=-1))

# Define our beloved crucial pixel
crucialPixel = (0,158,187)

# Construct a new, solid black image
im = Image.new('RGB', (1200,950))

# Neither should find crucialPixel in black image
result = loopy(im)
result = me(im)

# Insert the crucial pixel
im.putpixel((600,475), crucialPixel)

# Both should find crucialPixel
result = loopy(im)
result = me(im)
```

Comment: Totally valid point, but does not address the actual question.

Comment: wow thats actually impressive, 40x faster. Didn't know you could do this with numpy, really makes me think about all the things I don't know yet that could make my program 10x faster hahaha

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for keeping me on the *"straight and narrow"*. I have attempted to improve my answer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell is there a way for numpy to return the coordinates of the pixel? i need it since I need my mouse to click those coordinates

Comment: Try replacing `np.any(...)` by `Y,  X = np.argwhere(np.all(na==crucialPixel, axis=-1))` and looking at first element of X and Y if they are not None.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you! and one more thing, since this is in a separate function, if I wanna test more than 1 pixel (and get the value of all of them) I would need a separate function for each different pixel right? otherwise return would only return the value of 1

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit please? There may be a better way altogether - if, for example you are looking for any coloured pixels as opposed to grey ones, or if you are looking for any of 2 colours or any of 100 colours.